# Laravel: Is there a smarter way to return only users records instead of filtering them in each query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my Laravel application I have the following models:
User, Business, Profile, Subscriptions.
A user will have one business, a business will have one profile and many subscriptions.

In my Subscription controller many of my methods used to pull down the logged in users subscriptions require me to add something like the following:

```
Subscription::where('business_id', '=', Auth::user()->business->id)->active()->get();
```

In one query this may not be a problem, but I have many methods which pull the businesses subscription records and would like to know is there a smarter way to get only the businesses records while also adding additional scopes to the query.

Comment: Why associate the subscription with the business id, since the user has only one business?

Comment: This is to allow a business to be assigned to multiple users in future

Comment: Yeah, i  understand that. Even so it depends on your use-case and the rest of the workflow. Try using relations, instead of making those kind of queries. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Another possible hint. If you expect in the future to have more users belonging to a business. Start/create the logic around the 'Business'. E.g.  "a business has one/more users", "user has one subscription", "user belongs to a business"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have Laravel relation between Subscription and Business, you could rewrite this query like this:

```
$subs = Auth::user()->business->subscriptions()->active()->get();
```

The `->subscriptions()` part will return a query and you can chain additional scopes on it.

Comment: You should use `business()` instead of `business` as you don't need the business object here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that wouldn't work as `business()` would return a query object, not a model. Query object doesn't have relationships, model does. And you in fact need to know the `id` of business to get related subscriptions. Also by using `->business` you don't need to query it again, if you happen to have loaded the `business` somewhere sooner.

Answer (score 0):

If your relationships are set correctly then you could do one of the following.

```
$subscriptions = auth()->user()->business()->subscriptions()->active()->get();

$subscriptions = Subscription::whereHas('business', function ($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', auth()->id());
})->active()->get();
```